# How to get multiple results (rows) from database with same IDs in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, database, crud

I am using PHP to do CRUD operations over SQL server database. I don't use any PHP framework, custom only. Maybe there is some framework for what I need?

Using SQL Server Management Studio I created a view in database, then I use that view to select needed data in PHP.

The problem is for one row I have multiple items, so all of that items have the same row ID, and I can get result of only first row on my web application, but I need all items for that ID printed on my web application. How can I achieve that? If the row has only one item, it's fine, but I also need print data if there is more than one item, that's the problem.

Would any PHP framework help? Or maybe should I consider Python Django if that makes sense?

I can't access database I have on work today but I will give example for better understanding.

Rows in database example

ID   PC   Item
1    HP   Core i5
1    HP   4GB RAM
1    HP   Nvidia 1060
2    Dell Core i7
2    Dell 8GB RAM
3    Acer Core i7
3    Acer 4GB RAM
3    Acer Nvidia 1070
3    Acer SSD 240 GB

So for every PC I need to print all their components (items) in PHP. I hope you can understand now.

script.js and orderDetails.php files

```
function showDetails(button) {  // Show all details (items) of one row

var orderNumber = button.id;
// alert(orderNumber);
// AJAX call to get specific customer data
$.ajax({
    url: "orderDetails.php",
    method: "GET",
    data: {
        "orderNumberGET": orderNumber
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        // Parsing JSON string
        var rowData = JSON.parse(response);

        $("#acKey").text(rowData.RN_key);

        $("#item1").text(rowData.anNo);
        $("#item2").text(rowData.acIdent);
        $("#item3").text(rowData.anQty);

        $("#item4").text(rowData.anNo);
        $("#item5").text(rowData.acIdent);
        $("#item6").text(rowData.anQty);

       }
    }
});
}




// orderDetails.php file
<?php

require 'dbConnection.php';

if ($conn) {
$orderNumber = $_GET["orderNumberGET"];

$sql222 = "SELECT * FROM _Servisni_nalog_ToDo WHERE RN_key=$orderNumber";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql222);
$json = '';

// $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { // trying to print all with while loop, didn't succee. I can only get multiple json as response for every row (with same IDs) but don't know how to access any but first
    // echo $row['anNo'];
    $json .= json_encode($row);
    // echo $row;
}

echo $json;

// $array = json_decode($json, true);
// echo json_encode($row);
} 
else echo "No connection to database. Please check internet connection.";
```

Comment: Please provide some of your code with results and what you expect instead. This makes answering your question a lot easier.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. 
You should read this [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Provide the code you have, the table definitions and some sample data.

Comment: Ok I am aware of that, will post some code tomorrow. Thanks for fast reply guys

Comment: I added some code into original post, also I wrote example on result I get when I select from created view. I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: Anyone know solution for this?